# Plotly offline with flask

Tags: flask, plotly

How can I use plotly offline with flask . I know that plotly can be used offline with Ipython notebook , Can I use Plotly offline with flask ?
If not , can someone please suggest which python library can I use for 3 D visualisation in flask (offline library)

Answer (score 11):

Edit: Updated for current Plotly version

What you want to do is make functions that return the offline "plot" result as a html `<div>`. To do this, you call the offline.plot() method with the output_type="div" argument. This will return a pure string that you can then put in any flask template, and it will show the graph!

Also, make sure to include the plotly.js library in your static files and link to them in your html pages that show graphs.

This is an example of what I'm saying:

```
import plotly.graph_object as go
from plotly import io

fig = go.Figure(data=barChart, layout=barLayout)

div = io.to_html.plot(fig, show_link=False, output_type="div", include_plotlyjs=False)

return div
```

Comment: What exactly is this `offplot.plot()` or `offline.plot()` and where does it come from is unclear from both the question and this answer. Some elaboration will surely be welcome!

Comment: I wrote that answer a few years ago and from looking at the current Plotly documentation, the api seems to have changed a bit. From what I could gather the offplot.plot() method corresponds to the plotly.io.to_html() method they have now.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

@DarenThomas
In my usage, I simply import flask and create routes as usual.

```
import flask

# ... normal Dash stuff here

@app.server.route('/error.csv')
def serve_error():
    return flask.send_file('error.csv')
```

=====================================================================

For those looking in the future, this answer can be updated to include the Plotly side-project [Dash](https://github.com/plotly/dash). It comes out of the box with plotly/flask support and was extremely easy to get existing plotly graphs to show up in a web interface. For example:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

See also their [tutorial series](https://plot.ly/dash/).

Comment: what I'm having trouble figuring out is how to mix the plotly Dash world with a flask app and jinja2...

Comment: that does create two separate worlds though... I think it's not going to be easy to bridge the two... What I would love is to use a Jinja2 template for the site and then use dash for _just_ the plots and plot-related controls _on_ the page.

Comment: @daren I agree 100%. Looking in the Dash repository, it may be possible to subclass a Dash app and adjust how the renderer works with flask Response types? https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/dash/dash.py

Comment: looking forward to use flask + jinja + dash. Any updates?

Comment: may this can demonstrate what your are looking for https://plotlydashflask.hackersandslackers.app/